# Looking for a tool to annotate the Web page mockups I am given with sizing info before I craft HTML/CSS for them

Tags: website-design, measurement

I usually get Web page designs that I have to craft HTML/CSS for.

At the moment I use tools such as OS X's own Preview to size up various parts of the designs I get in order to extract widths and heights that I can use in my CSS rules.

Is there a tool that can come handy for doing this? For example, when I draw a rectangle around a specific component in the page, I want it to also permanently show the width/height of that rectangle.

Looking forward for your suggestions.

*EDIT*: I found a few "ruler" apps on App Store that are very helpful but are not exactly what I am looking for (e.g. they do not annotate the image itself, but rather are on-screen tools).

Comment: Measuring pixels is a painful way to build web sites. It's a rather antiquated model. But if this is your your group does things, I'd pass the buck...have those making the mockups be responsible for annotating the dimensions.

Comment: What is the source file you're receiving? PSD?

Comment: @DA01 Could you please elaborate? What is the modern and current approach?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum PNG.

Comment: Do you have Photoshop?

Comment: For wireframes and numbers, I find pencil and paper much more useful

Answer (score 1):

The info pane in photoshop can do this easily. However nothing I have seen puts this information on the image automatically. you could just add it yourself with the text tool of photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to place callouts and measurements on the comp page(s), and you are on a Mac, just open the file(s) in Preview and then use the Annotation tools; lines, ovals, comments, etc...  This is what I normally use for Image and PDF comps with clients.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[SpecKing](http://wuwacorp.com/) plugin for photoshop will do the job

Comment: You should remark that the tool is commercial. Please give not only a link, explain how the problem could be solved with this tool.

Answer (score 0):

for annotation and sharing - i love using SKITCH PLUS for this. its free too

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Adobe products, you should be able to get dimensions for any element in your design by selecting it and viewing stats in the Info Panel. I do not know of any tool that will permanently label your designs with dimensional labels.